# SQL Server Row Into Column

Tags: sql-server, row

We have a table showing amounts (CHGCNT) for 3 dates (5-9-2016, 5-10-2016, 5-11-2016) for each store & Depts.

[image]

I want to be able to see the records in a table like this:

[image]

I already applied the following query

```html
declare @dt as datetime
declare @dt1 as varchar(10) 
declare @dt2 as varchar(10) 
declare @dt3 as varchar(10) 
select distinct @dt = min(effdt) from  [HQExtract].[dbo].[FSM_PRICE_TAGCOUNT]
-- print CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt, 110) + ' ---- ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt+1 , 110) 

set @dt1 = CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt, 110)
set @dt2 = CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt +1 , 110)
set @dt3 = CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt + 2 , 110)

--print @dt1 + ' ---- ' + @dt2 + '-----' + @dt3



SELECT   DEPTNM, DEPT,  [@dt1] ,   [@dt2] , [@dt3]
FROM   [HQExtract].[dbo].[FSM_PRICE_TAGCOUNT]
PIVOT
(
       SUM(CHGCNT)
       FOR effdt IN ( [@dt1] ,   [@dt2] , [@dt3])
) AS P
```

but it is returning dates  [image]

Comment: You shouldn't hard code your columns that you're pivoting by. You should figure them out dynamically. Just google SQL pivot and you should find a suitable answer.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051655/sqlserver-table-row-to-column-data/37054088#37054088

Answer (score 0):

I like the SUM-CASE approach:

```
SELECT deptnm,
SUM(CASE WHEN effdt = '2016-05-09' THEN chgcnt ELSE 0 END) "2016-05-09",
SUM(CASE WHEN effdt = '2016-05-10' THEN chgcnt ELSE 0 END) "2016-05-10",
SUM(CASE WHEN effdt = '2016-05-11' THEN chgcnt ELSE 0 END) "2016-05-11",
SUM(effdt) Total
FROM [HQExtract].[dbo].[FSM_PRICE_TAGCOUNT]
GROUP BY deptnm;
```

Comment: Of course my answer only helps in the specific case you mention. ;)